# DSolve returning { } when given my ODE

Tags: differential-equations

Why does this code return `{}`?

```
sol1 = 
  DSolve[
    miuP * F * D[deltaP[x], x] + Dp * D[deltaP[x], {x,2}] + G * Exp[- alpha * x] == 
      deltaP[x] / Tp, 
    deltaP, x];
```

All the constants are non-zero.

#### Edit

I forgot to say the following about G.

```
G = (1.86559*10^38 lambda)/(1 + (0.338476 Sqrt[-0.4 + V])/BesselJ[1, 3.26534 Sqrt[-0.4 + V]])
```

where `V` and `lambda` are parameters.

Comment: Your code works as is for me (V10.0.1, V9.0.1).  What version are you using?  Also, try it from a fresh kernel, in case you have some definitions lurking.

Comment: thank you  Michael E2. my version is 9.0.1.0

Comment: So does it work, then?  (It works for me in 9.0.1.0, but I did it with all of the constants being undefined symbols.)

Comment: excuse me michael. i edit my question. G is not constant.

Answer (score 6):

It works in V10 with `G` defined as in the update to the question but not in V9.  It works in both versions of *Mathematica* if `G` is undefined.  So there are two ways to get the solution in V9: 1) Compute the solution with a symbolic `G` and then define `G`; 2) [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rationalize.html) `G`, solve, and numericize the result with `N`:

```
G = (1.86559*10^38 lambda)/(1 + (0.338476 Sqrt[-0.4 + V])/
      BesselJ[1, 3.26534 Sqrt[-0.4 + V]]);

(* Method 1 *)
Block[{G},
 sol1 = DSolve[(miuP * F * D[deltaP[x], x]) + (Dp * D[deltaP[x], {x, 2}]) +
                 (G * Exp[-alpha*x]) == (deltaP[x]/Tp), 
               deltaP, x];
 ]

(* Method 2 *)
sol1 = DSolve[(miuP * F * D[deltaP[x], x]) + (Dp * D[deltaP[x], {x, 2}]) +  
                (Rationalize[G, 0] * Exp[-alpha*x]) == (deltaP[x]/Tp),
              deltaP, x] // N;
```

The solution is rather long and is omitted.

Comment: thanks a lot for your very very helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you correct the Syntax from deltaP to deltap[] there is no problem:

```
sol1 = DSolve[(miuP*F*D[deltaP[x], x]) + (Dp*
      D[deltaP[x], {x, 2}]) + (G*Exp[-alpha*x]) == (deltaP[x]/Tp), 
  deltaP[x], x]

(* {{deltaP[x] -> (2*Dp*G* ...) a long Expression, with two constants C[1], C[2]  *)
```

Regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: thank you Wolfgang.i refine my code, but it returns {}.

Comment: I have Version 8.